# Iterating over multiple dictionaries with dynamic variables:

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, global-variables

I have multiple dictionaries and the number of dictionaries is not fixed, e.g.

```
year0 = {'A':'alpha','B':'beta','C':'gamma'}
year1 = {'D':'delta','E':'epsilon','F':'zeta'}
...
yearN = {dictionary N}
```

My objective is to loop through the dictionaries and write them to new worksheets in the same Excel document, using openpyxl. My code is as follows:

```
31. for name in all_variables:
32. if name.startswith('year'):
33.    workbook = Workbook()
34.    sheet = workbook.active
35.    year_num = 0
36.    row = 1
37.    sheet.title = "Year"+str(year_num)
38.    for key in name.keys():
39.        sheet.cell(row, 1, key)
40.        sheet.cell(row, 2, name[key])
41.        row += 1
42.    year_num += 1
43.    sheet = workbook.create_sheet()
```

However, the code throws the following error:

```
line 38, in <module> for key in name.keys(): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Even when I hardcode the dictionary name in line 38, like so:

```
31. for name in all_variables:
32. if name.startswith('year'):
33.    workbook = Workbook()
34.    sheet = workbook.active
35.    year_num = 0
36.    row = 1
37.    sheet.title = "Year"+str(year_num)
38.    for key in year0.keys():
39.        sheet.cell(row, 1, key)
40.        sheet.cell(row, 2, name[key])
41.        row += 1
42.    year_num += 1
43.    sheet = workbook.create_sheet()
```

line 40 then throws the following error:

```
line 40 in <module> sheet.cell(row, 2, name[key]) TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help on how to do this iteration properly? Thank you!

Comment: What is all_variables?

Comment: all_variables = dir()

Comment: so the dictionnary name encoded in "name" from all_variables is a string?

Comment: Yes. Using: print(type(name)) yields <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the upper code, your `name` is a string, not yet a variable with that name. In specific, if it iterate to `year0`, it becomes `'year0'`, not `{'A':'alpha','B':'beta','C':'gamma'}`. In your case, you can add this line after the if-statement:

`name = eval(name)`.

Now your `name` becomes a dictionary.